# Terraform conditional provisioning

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have an issue with Terraform provisioning. When I run terraform first time I am using SSH key generated in AWS console. This key is being added to `ubuntu` user (it's Ubuntu 16.04 AMI). Then I run `remote-exec` provisioning:

```
provisioner "remote-exec" {
  inline = [
  "sudo apt -y update && sudo apt install -y python"
  ]
  connection {
    user = "ubuntu"
    private_key = "${file("${var.aws_default_key_name}.pem")}"
  }
}
```

I need python being installed so I can use Ansible later. That's the only place where I need this key, never more, because I create my own user with my private key. However, when I try to run terraform later it searches for a file `file("${var.aws_default_key_name}.pem"`.
Now I have a question how to skip this provisioning on subsequent runs?

I don't want to store SSH key in the repository.

I could create an empty file to "trick" terraform, but I don't like this solution.

Any better ideas?

Answer (score 5):

Instead of doing provisioning in the `aws_instance` block, move it out to a [`null_resource`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/null_resource.html) block, with appropriate triggers.

```
resource "aws_instance" "cluster" {
  count = 3

  # ...
}

resource "null_resource" "cluster" {
  # Changes to any instance of the cluster requires re-provisioning
  triggers {
    cluster_instance_ids = "${join(",", aws_instance.cluster.*.id)}"
  }

  connection {
    host = "${element(aws_instance.cluster.*.public_ip, 0)}"
  }

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [something]
  }
}
```

If your triggers do not change the null_resource provisioning will not be triggered on subsequent runs.

Comment: I will test and let you know, but seems promising!

Answer (score 1):

[Sparrowform](https://github.com/melezhik/sparrowform) is a lightweight provisioner for Terraform based infrastructure. The benefits against other provision tools, is that stage of `terraform apply` which does infrastructure bootstrap **is decoupled**  from provision stage, so you may do this:

```
$ terraform apply # does infra bootstrap

$ nano sparrowfile # Sparrowdo equivalent for remote-exec chunk

#!/usr/bin/env perl6

bash 'apt -y update';
package-install 'python';

$ sparrowform --ssh_user=my-user --ssh_private_key=/path/to/key  # do provision stage
```

Obviously you are free **not to run** `sparrowform` in **subsequent runs**. It does it's job (install ansible related dependencies, that is it). Then you drop your initial `ssh_private_key` and go with new private key (  ansible related I guess ?)

PS. disclosure - I am the tool author