# Can we skip the execution of some part in terraform resource

Tags: terraform

I'm trying to spin up the oci load balancer using oci stock manager we are doing this deployment with jenkins so few users are not willing to attach their backendsets with SSL but some users do so in that can case how can we skip the execution when the user want to attach the ssl to backendset

is it possible to skip the execution for some part terraform resource?

Comment: You can do that with variables and the resource count: https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#count-multiple-resource-instances-by-count
If you can provide some code of what you are doing I can give you a concrete example

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Terraform conditional provisioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45177941/terraform-conditional-provisioning)